# Multiple unique constraint performance

Tags: postgresql

Imagine we have those tables with no primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  name1 INT,
  name2 INT,
  name3 INT,
  
  UNIQUE (name1, name2, name3)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (
  name1 INT,
  name2 INT,
  name3 INT,
  
  UNIQUE (name1, name2)
);
```

I feel like those two tables are exactly the same somehow, I am not sure if the combinations are the same. If you have a trick to know about combinations, I ll be more than happy to know about it.

In case of performance is it the same to add an unique constraint on 2 columns and an unique constraint on let say 5 or 6 columns? I imagine that we are just adding one pointer per constraint?

Answer (score 2):

Each unique SQL constraint translates into a definition stored in a system table (the set of these system tables forming what is called the CATALOG) but also into an index which speeds up the verification of this uniqueness. The number of columns in the index as the length of the information has little influence on the duration of this check because the search algorithm is logarithmic...

In your case, the difference of performance will be negligible

Comment: In that case, do you suggest adding constraint on all columns to avoid duplicate, on tables that don't have primary keys? 
Or is it a bad design?

Comment: It is a very bad design. Your business rules dictate the constraints. Suppose you constrain (uniquely) each column and have a table `customers` with a column for `state`. With your constraint you can only have 1 customer per state. Is that valid business rule? BTW your tables are not the same. `Test` would allow the rows (1,2,3) and (1,2,4) to exist, `Test2` would would allow either one, but not both.

Comment: For adding constraint uniquely on each column I agree, I will have 1 customer per state.
But adding unique constraint on multiple column `Unique (customer, state)` will work fine.
I agree that my business rule dictate the constraints. But we could have a scenario where we have to do a data migration, those constraints could clean the data.